# How the extend the axes in a plot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot

I am trying to figure out how to extend my x-axis in the following plot, in order to fit all the markers neatly and make them all readable:

[image]

I also attempted to convert my x-values to actual dates following the advice of another user, using the following command, but the plot doesn't have the proper distribution anymore, and the dates need to instead be 'Month Day' rather than 'Month Year':

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: If it is okey for you, try to use x-ticks vertical rotation: `plt.xticks(rotation = 'vertical')`.

Comment: No screenshots of code. Please also include the code as text by [edit]-ing your question. See [reprex] and [ask].

Comment: @PolinaDyachkova this worked perfectly! Very elegant solution, thank you!